# Need some assistance with an user not being able to send a message when the length of the input is 0

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment ive got my code set up so that the user can send a message to the chatbot on my website.

What i would like to do is, prevent the user from sending a message if userText is empty. Below is what i have so far:

```js
function getUserResponse(){
    var userText = $('#textInput').val();  
    
    if(userText.val() == 0){
    
    }else{
        var userHTML = "<p class='userText'><span>"+userText+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> <img src= {% static 'images/userIcon.png' %} width=50px height=50px  style='vertical-align: middle;' >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p>";
        $('#textInput').val("");
    }
    

    $('#chatbot').append(userHTML);

    $.get('/chatbotModel/getResponse',{userMessage:userText}).done(function(data){
        var returnedMessage = "<p class='botText'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src= {% static 'images/chatbot.png' %} width=50px height=50px  style='vertical-align: middle;' >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span>"+data+"</span/></p>";
        $('#chatbot').append(returnedMessage)
    })
}
    
$('#buttonInput').click(function(){
    getUserResponse()
})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Comment: `var userText = $('#textInput').val();` and you do `if(userText.val() == 0)` I am sure you have an error in your console. A string does not have a .val() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So check if the string is empty by looking at the length and if it is, exit....

```
var userText = $('#textInput').val().trim();  
if(userText.length === 0) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has contributed towards giving me suggestions for this query. I have now managed to solve the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

- Try with:

  ```
  if ( userText.val().length == 0 ){
  ```

It would read the number of characters of the input, if it´s **0**, it would return `true`.

---

- You can abbreviate it like this:

  ```
  if ( !userText.val().length ){
  ```

Using the `!` operator, which transform a number into a boolean: if number is **0** it would return `true`, else, returns `false`.

---

### A more complex way to do it

- The `verify_input()` function would read each character. If there isn´t any valid character (*from ascii code 33 to 165*) it would return `false`:

```js
function submit() {
  var val = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  if (verify_input(val)) {
    console.log("Verified");
  } else {
    console.log("Denied");
  }
}

function verify_input(myval) {
  var myval_arr = myval.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < myval_arr.length; i++) {
    if (myval_arr[i].charCodeAt(0) >= 33 && myval_arr[i].charCodeAt(0) <= 165) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="myinput">
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

---

**PD**: do not declare the `userText` variable like this:

```
var userText = $('#textInput').val();
```

Just declare with the input element:

```
var userText = $('#textInput');
```

Comment: This would still allow the user to send an empty message though